# How to conditionally return custom error message in EXPRESS-VALIDATOR

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

In my case express-validator will return its custom message `Invalid value(s)` if either `check()`s, passed to `oneOf()` will not pass validation. However I want it to somehow return the custom error message that I specified, on each failed `check`.

Here's my middleware:

```
    [
        check(`username`, `username is required`)
            .not()
            .isEmpty(),
        oneOf([
            check(`password`, `password is required`)
                .not()
                .isEmpty(),
            check(`password`, `password is too short`).isLength({ min: 3 })
        ])
    ]
```

I want it it to return either `password is required` or `password is too short`, instead of `Invalid value(s)`. Thanks!

Comment: Second param to the `oneOf(<checks>, <message>)` function can be a message to overwrite the default _Invalid value(s)_ https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#oneofvalidationchains-message

Comment: @Molda I need a message depending on which `check` failed